# Importing a file to a web page [SELENIUM]

Tags: html, selenium, file, import

I am creating a selenium script to automatically log in to a webpage, and then import a .xls file. However I am stuck in the part when the webpage prompts me to select a file from my computer. How do I code to send the keys with the file path and press "enter"? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To upload a file with Selenium you can send the file's path to input element with type file on the web page.
If, for example your file path is `C:\your_file.xls` your code will be something like this:

```
file_path = 'C:\your_file.xls'
upload_input = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="file"]')
upload_input.send_keys(file_path)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! But how do I find the exact xpath from the dialog box that opens up so I can use the code to input the file? I have tried to inspect the full page with no luck :(. THank you!!

Comment: You do not need to open that dialog at all! You just need to send the file path to that input element.